# Floor, int conversion is not working correctly for large values

Tags: c++, int, floor

I have got a problem. I got this function in a class "invKin" to set some parameters before I ran a simulation:

```
void IK_mm4::set_timesetting(double *T_horiz_, double *delta_t_)
{
  T_horiz  = T_horiz_;
  delta_t  = delta_t_;

  k_end = (int)floor((*T_horiz)/(*delta_t));

  cout << "k_end = " << k_end <<endl;
}
```

It is invoked in my main-file with

```
...
double delta_t = 5e-3;
double *T_desired = new double(5.0);
...
invKin.set_timesetting(T_desired,&delta_t);
...
```

The problem is now. At the PC at my university everything is fine and k_end has the value '1000' as it should have. At my home PC the system is somehow giving back the value '999'. If I change the value of *T_desired down to '0.05' cout is giving the right value of '10' at both PCs.

I have already checked to use a variable

```
double k_end_test = (*T_horiz)/(*delta_t);
```

that is giving the correct solution of '1000'. The error must be in the floor function or the int-conversion. If I do

```
int k_end_test2 = (int)(k_end_test);
```

or

```
double k_end_test2 = floor(k_end_test);
```

the result is always '999'.

Does somebody have an idea where this can come from?

I am thankful for any kind of hints! Thank You!

Comment: Omg, your code is so confusing! Did you include the required header for `floor()`? You should single-step the code to dig deeper into what values are where.

Comment: If you require an exact answer and cannot tolerate rounding, don't use floating point! You must read [this paper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Wow, allocating lone doubles on the heap. That does not sound like efficient way to do things.

Comment: What happens if you print `0.005` with precision of 20 digits after the decimal point? Is it wise to use `floor` after doing arithmetic with numbers like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the nature of limited-precision representations.

For example, consider six decimal digits of precision. This is not what `double` uses, of course, but the concept is precisely the same. `1/3` is `.333333` with six digits of decimal precision. So `30 * (1/3)` is `9.99999`. If you round down to an integer, you get `9`, not `10`. This is the problem you are seeing.

If you don't want this behavior, don't use floating point.

It may suffice to add a small "delta" to the value you pass to `floor`.

Comment: Hm. Ok,I get the point. Can you specify "don't use floating point"? If i try to set 'delta_t = 0.005' instead of 'delta_t = 5e-3', that doesn't change anything.

Second question: why is the code running on the system at university and on my system it is not?

Comment: Likely on one system the value happens to stay in a floating point register and on the other system, it happens to get read out to memory and read back in. As for not using floating point, use integers or longs instead. For example, you can store delta_t in integer millionths -- 5,000 instead of .005.